# SQL Create Statement for Multiple Columns Containing all Given Values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database. What I'm asking is when I have a table where `A`, `B` and `C` are the column names and the other numbers beyond are the values:

```
A | B | C
---------
0 | 1 | 2
1 | 2 | 3
2 | 1 | 3
0 | 3 | 2
```

And my search requires that the row must contain `1` and `3` the valid rows would be row 2 and row 3 since they have both the values. Is there an easier way than to create a huge nested query with lots of `IN` operators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use two `in` statements:

```
select *
from table t
where 1 in (A, B, C) and 3 in (A, B, C);
```

Comment: The thing is it's about Strings ... and `where '%1%' LIKE (A, B, C) and '%3%' LIKE (A, B, C);` won't work

Comment: Then you should ask *another* question.  This question is clearly about equality, with the strong suggestion that the values are integers.  If you have another question, ask it as a new question.  If you edit this one, you will invalidate the answers of everyone who tried to help you, and bad answers draw downvotes.

Comment: Yeah I realize I asked wrong, but your answer gave me the correct hint so I guess it's ok though...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something like this might work..
(UNTESTED)

```
Select tn.*, case when 1 in (a,b,c) then 1 end as isOne, 
       case when 3 in (a,b,c) then 1 end as isThree
FROM tableName tn
having isOne = 1 and isThree=1
```

or

```
with cte (Select tn.*, case when 1 in (a,b,c) then 1 end as isOne, 
           case when 3 in (a,b,c) then 1 end as isThree
    FROM tableName tn)
SELECT * from CTE where isOne = 1 and isThree=1
```

I'm not sure if the having will evaluate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@GordonLindoff's answer works for testing equality.  If you have to use LIKE, however, you'll have to use regular logic:

```
WHERE ((A LIKE '%1%' AND (B LIKE '%3%' OR C LIKE '%3%'))
    OR (B LIKE '%1%' AND (A LIKE '%3%' OR C LIKE '%3%'))
    OR (C LIKE '%1%' AND (A LIKE '%3%' OR B LIKE '%3%')))
```

Bear in mind that this will probably be pretty inefficient, given how LIKE functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array from each row and check if these arrays overlap with [1,3]:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM t WHERE ARRAY[1,3] <@ ARRAY[a,b,c]
```